# Update BigQuery access policy using golang

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

The documentation doesn't mention any options:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls#update_an_access_policy

Are there any ways to achieve this (similar to https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#granting_access_to_a_dataset)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#hdr-Querying - this works not only with SELECT statements. So running a "GRANT" through that solves my issue.